# Why doesn’t [NSDictionary allKeys] return a set?

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary

Is there a reason for `NSDictionary` to return its keys as `NSArray` instead of `NSSet`? The documentation already states that the order of the keys in the array is undefined, it would sound logical to use a set.

Comment: Interesting question. Have to wonder if it's purely because NSArray was around before NSSet was in the days of NeXTSTEP yore, but that's utter speculation on my part.

Comment: Nice question, and i would also assume its because NSArray was around first and is a more widely used/understood/known structure than a set. I don't recall, but perhaps when you return the keys array it sorts them then, providing an easier way to iterate through?

Comment: [File an enhancement request.](http://bugreporter.apple.com/)

Comment: +1 Great question. I've wondered this also.

Comment: +2 Wonderfu wonderful question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets tend to be somewhat neglected in API design. They'll be included most of the time, but usually long after all the other standard data structures. Add on top of that the fact that besides the very recent NSFastEnumeration, there is no general collection or sequence protocol in Objective-C — every collection class is completely independent of all the others — and it becomes very hard to switch to sets after an API has already been written that returns arrays.

Comment: *cough* `NSEnumerator` has been around since at least 10.0

Comment: @Mike Abdullah: The class has existed for a long time. A consistent way to *get* one from an arbitrary collection eludes us even to this day. And even that provides no more functionality than fast enumeration.

Comment: `-objectEnumerator` seems pretty consistent to me.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that Apple is using `NSArray` all over the place (and most programmers as well), so this choice comes naturally - and changing it now would come at a high cost. And *if* using arrays internally, a copy of an immutable array is much cheaper than building a set just for the sake of mathematical elegance.

Also note that `NSSet` and `NSArray` don't have a common parent (well, except `NSObject`, of course), so abstracting this interface is also impossible (except for returning something that conforms to `NSFastEnumeration`).

Just wild speculation, of course. ;-)

Comment: I’m not that much into mathematical elegance. I came across the issue in a test where I wanted to do something like `[[dict allKeys] isEqual:expectedOutput]` and realized that I’ll have to get rid of the key order that should not have been there in the first place.

Comment: I am testing some code that detects class properties and returns them as a dictionary, keys being the property names and values the property attributes. This particular test wants to know if the analyzer detects all properties and gets their names right, therefore `expectedOutput` is something like `[NSSet setWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil]`. Or would be, if the dictionary returned the keys as a set.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, since `-allKeys` returns a *copy* of the keys (it's not backed by the dictionary) that creating an `NSSet` is a lot of overhead (building a tree or hash table or whatever) when compared to just dumping the keys into a flat array.

Comment: Not according to the docs. `-allKeys` does **not** return a copy of the keys. It returns the keys that the dictionary is actually using. Confusion may have arisen because *setting* a key will copy that key.

Comment: Let me clarify: it doesn't copy the keys themselves, but it returns a collection of keys that is a duplicate of the collection contained in the dictionary. That is, the *pointers* to the key objects are copied over to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would want to do something with the keys, in which case it is simpler to use this NSDictionary method:

```
- (NSSet<KeyType> *)keysOfEntriesPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(KeyType key, ObjectType obj, BOOL *stop))predicate NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

This saves time because now you don't need to filter your array using a predicate, you can just perform your test in here and you get a set back. Simple.

Furthermore, you can take advantage of multi-processor concurrency by passing the concurrent enumeration option to this version of the method:

```
- (NSSet<KeyType> *)keysOfEntriesWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts passingTest:(BOOL (^)(KeyType key, ObjectType obj, BOOL *stop))predicate NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

Answer (score -3):

use use c++, std::map provides access to its keys as a set.  the set returned is even "live" , the set reflects the ongoing current set of keys.  of course you are free to make a copy as well.

Comment: How does that even remotely answer the question?

Comment: Not only fails to answer the question, but is also incorrect.